# Adapter to plug home audio system speakers into computer

Tags: speakers, adapter, stereo

I'm wondering if there is an adapter I can use to plug two speakers that came with my home audio system into a laptop. My laptop has an auxiliary port (not sure what the technical name is) that I plug my headphones into so ideally I would like to use that for these speakers also. I wasn't sure how to title my searches when I researched this due to not knowing what the speaker extensions are even called, but I tend to assume there is an adapter for everything these days! The impedance is 8 (not sure if this matters). Ultimately, the stereo itself doesn't work, but the speakers do so I'm trying to figure out if they're worth salvaging.

The model of the system is **Sony MHC-EC619iP**. The speaker extensions have two adjoined "prongs" that plug into the back of the system under "Left" and "Right".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an amplifier as the laptop won’t drive those speakers directly.

An amplifier with a remote control works well and I do this with my laptop & a Kenwood amp driving  pair of Linn bookshelf speakers.